# Disambiguate `weightlifting` tag

Tags: discussion

Weightlifting is generally taken to mean Olympic weightlifting, whereas weight lifting means lifting weights generally. Should we split this tag up? It seems to create confusion and misuse of the term for no good reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a little nuanced. The general public, and even experienced strength trained athletes probably don't have that etymology nailed.

I'd leave weightlifting (and weight lifting) alone, and just have olympic-lifting. Just my opinion.